# Java Swing knowledge for a web-developer

Tags: java, swing

There are many good books about Java and (almost) every one contains a big section about Swing.

I'm involved in web-development. Is knowing about "Swing" useful for Java web-development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applets can be embedded into a web-app., and applications can connect to them.  Either provide a richer GUI than is possible with JavaScript/HTML, but unless they bring something specific to the web-app. (rarely the case), it is better to avoid the rich client GUIs & stick with D/HTML.

Comment: good point about applets,actually forgot about them

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps learn patterns that could be reused in a web application, but no, Swing is not used in webapps.

Comment: that I mentioned also in my question - techniques, so looks like i may take patterns(approaches) from Swing

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. Swing isn't used at all in web development, unless your web app involves Java applets -- Java GUI code which is downloaded to the client and run inside the web browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop web application using a 'component' approach - like GWT - having knowledge of Swing can help you.

GWT or Vaadin framework are using widgets (window, panel, menu, text area) and layout them to organize the client view. The application is not going from pages to pages but instead have a single entry point that will show and hide windows and panels.

In this way they are very close to Swing (even if they are simpler to handle). 
You'll find easier to switch from Swing to GWT (and vis-versa) than to switch from a page based framework (like struts) to GWT.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding the **concepts** involved in Swing can help in understanding the **concepts** of Java Server Faces.

But no, other than in applets, Swing is not used for web development.